# Can I get back a deleted folder on a network drive?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2019

This morning we had an employee quit all of a sudden. She had a folder on a shared network drive from one of our servers. i am trying to find the folder she deleted because there was data that we need. can i get this data back?

Comment: No one can answer this, with this little info. In general I'd say: no. Data needs to be recovered from the server's drive(s) which will be constantly written to and so good chance the data is overwritten by now.

Comment: What OS is on the server? If Windows, try the Recycle Bin.

Comment: It depends on how the employee connected but Explorer and good Explorer replacements delete the files because it cannot put them in the recycle bin. This can happen, and given normal server activity, it is highly unlikely you can retrieve the files. They should be in the server backup.

Comment: I apologize, the OS is windows server 2019 Standard. this server has mapped drive for all users to create folders and store data. she had a folder in her name that she used for storing data. she would collaborate with other employees and copy from what she had saved in that folder. this morning she walked in and deleted it so my question is, where can I start looking to see if I can find the deleted data?

Comment: It would not have gone to the recycle bin.  If you are able to pull the drive down, it is possible but unlikely to recover data from it.  The is especially true since other people have probably been pounding the drive with other activity and overwriting important blocks.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: Why wouldn't it go to the Recycle Bin ?

Comment: The files may have gone to the Recycle Bin on the employee's computer. Did you look there?  The employee may have emptied the Recycle Bin when they deleted the files.

Comment: I did and yes the recycle bin on her computer has been deleted.

Comment: Do you have normal Server backups that you can use?

Comment: im fairly new with windows server, could you point me in the right direction to see If there are backups?

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: @harrymc , because there is no recycle bin for network drives (by default) and I have yet to ever see that option enabled.

Comment: The network drive is backed up by a Windows folder. Why wouldn't it be in the Restore Bin?

Comment: @harrymc , the recycle bin is local to the volume it is on.  When you delete something on a network drive, it doesn't go to the recycle bin.  It goes straight to the ether.  This has always been true but I guess the network API has been extended but nobody enables it.  Imagine the headache of an IT person trying to manage the space of 200 different SIDs worth of recycle bins.  If this isn't the case.. then it is new to me and would love to learn.  I learn lots from you mr MC so I am not talking smack! :-P

Comment: @juiceman: You'll need to try file-recovery products.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: I did a small test on Windows 10, and it's true that a folder deleted through a network share doesn't go to the Recycle Bin, and neither do files. Probably a leftover from a previous Windows version that Microsoft never fixed. I also learned something new here today.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: Apparently there is way to [enable the Recycle Bin on a folder under `C:\Users\Username`](https://www.remosoftware.com/info/enable-recycle-bin-mapped-network-drives), but I'm not going to test it.

Comment: @juiceman - “I'm fairly new with windows server, could you point me in the right direction to see If there are backups?” - You should ask somebody in your office familiar with your data backup retention policy. If you don’t have one then the file is likely permanently gone. File recovery on a network share that’s actively being used is a waste of time.

Comment: You either have backups of the networked drive, or you're hosed. If your company has a competent person running the server, and they haven't been prevented from doing backups by their management, no problem.